# MongoDB can´t connect

Tags: java, mongodb

Basically i have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.spi.dns.DnsClient com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.getDnsClient()'
```

This is my code:

```
public MongoDatabase connect() {
    try {
        String connectionString = "mongodb+srv://dev:<censored>@cluster0.ji1ynnc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=AtlasApp";

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);

        return mongoClient.getDatabase("dashboard");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I searched for other people facing the same problem but no one seems to ever saw this error
The only answer that i found was this:

```
public MongoDatabase connect() {
    try {
        String connectionString = "mongodb+srv://dev:<censored>@cluster0.ji1ynnc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=AtlasApp";

        ServerApi serverApi = ServerApi.builder().version(ServerApiVersion.V1).build();

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .serverApi(serverApi)
                .build();

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        return mongoClient.getDatabase("dashboard");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But this doesn´t work either, it just produces the same error

Comment: *NoSuchMethodError* indicated incompatible jars in your classpath

Comment: Are you importing the jars manually?

Comment: try these steps: Clean and Rebuild the Project, Update the Libraries, Dependency Management, Clear Dependency Cache, Check Classpath, Update the MongoDB Driver.
Once you have performed these steps, you should be able to resolve the "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" error. I hope this works, it went smoothly for me like this

Comment: Now i have an other error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.internal.connection.Cluster com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings, com.mongodb.connection.ServerSettings, com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings, com.mongodb.connection.StreamFactory, com.mongodb.connection.StreamFactory, com.mongodb.MongoCredential, com.mongodb.event.CommandListener, java.lang.String, com.mongodb.MongoDriverInformation, java.util.List, com.mongodb.ServerApi)'

Comment: It looks like you are connecting to MongoDB Atlas.  Atlas uses Service DNS records (SRV).  You must have access to the public DNS service to gain access and decompose the service records into traditional A records.  Also, since this is Atlas, you need to make sure your public IP address is added to the MongoDB Atlas access list on the left hand pane of Atlas.

Comment: All things you mentioned is true for me i even have the problem on two separate setups and of course my IP address is added

Comment: And for @DiegoBorba i use gradle and this is the way the jar is implemented (exactly like the MongoDB Docs show it): implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.10.2'